# Moving a JS Function from on load to when called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I have the following JS function which I have been using for quite some time, copied almost verbatim out of another Stack Overflow question. I have found that rather that as my needs have changed, I need to instead call this function from a button and pass the value of count as a parameter rather than tracking it in the function.

I tried changing it to "function addInventory(count)" and moving the var template line inside of it, however Firebug reports "SyntaxError: missing variable name" for the var inventory line and I can't figure out whats wrong.

What is the issue with this?

Original Function:

```
$(function()
{
    var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone(),
        inventoryCount = 0;

    var addInventory = function()
    {
        inventoryCount++;
        var inventory = template.clone().find(':input').each(function()
        {
            var newLabel = "invItem[" + inventoryCount + "]";
            $(this).prev().attr('id', newLabel);
            $(this).prev().attr('name', newLabel);
        }).end()
        .attr('id', 'inv' + inventoryCount)
        .appendTo('#inventoryItems > fieldset');
    };

    $('.btnAddInventory').click(addInventory);
});
```

New Function:

```
function addInventory(count)
{
    var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone(),

    var inventory = template.clone().find(':input').each(function()
    {
        var newLabel = "invItem[" + count + "]";
        $(this).prev().attr('id', newLabel);
        $(this).prev().attr('name', newLabel);
    }).end()
    .attr('id', 'inv' + count)
    .appendTo('#inventoryItems > fieldset');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the **;** after the *var template* line. Change

```
 var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone(),
```

to

```
 var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone();
```

This will solve the "SyntaxError: missing variable name" problem.

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly. For some reason that exact code (with the error) worked fine for me for quite some time, not sure why.

Comment: Haha happens sometime with me also! :))